# Como salvar dados de um CArrayDataProvider no Banco de dados?

Tags: php, sql, yii

Olá, tenho um CArrayDataProvider e queria salvar seus dados em uma tabela através de um model, já tentei de diversas formas e não obtive resultado, qual seria a melhor forma de salva-lo?

Minha ultima tentativa até agora:

```
                    foreach($usuarioItensAvulso as $value)
                    {
                        $model->cod_material = $value["cod_material"];
                        $model->des_justificativa = $value["des_justificativa"];
                        $model->des_quantidade = $value["des_quantidade"];
                        //Se as informaï¿½ï¿½es forem vï¿½lidas, salvar e direcionar para a pï¿½gina do Visualizar.
                        if ($model->validate())
                        {
                            //Faz a inclusï¿½o do texto
                            $model->save();
                            //Exibe mensagem de salvo com sucesso
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Salvo com sucesso.');
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1 ° verificar se todos os valores necessários para salvar, se não houver o `$model->validate()` sempre retornarão false e nunca serão salvos.
2 ° se você está trabalhando com um array `$userItensAvulso` então você tem que inicializar seu modelo toda vez que você inicia o`for` pq senao vai ser reescrito o primeiro a ser inserido

```
foreach($usuarioItensAvulso as $value)
{
    $model = new Nome_do_modelo; // iniciar o teu modelo pq senao vai ser reescrito o primeiro a ser insertado

    $model->cod_material = $value["cod_material"];
    $model->des_justificativa = $value["des_justificativa"];
    $model->des_quantidade = $value["des_quantidade"];

    if ($model->validate())
    {
        $model->save();
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Salvo com sucesso.');
    }
}
```

seria bom poder ver todo o codigo dessa função y tmb o codigo do teu modelo mais especificamente a funsao das regras para poder orientar melhor sobro o que estas a fazer